# python: consecutive __getitem__() calls in inherited classes?

Tags: python, inheritance, call, python-2.x

I encountered a problem that I do not understand, and it is quite complicated so I give my best to break it down here. Please have a look at the following implementation. My question is: why does the Father class call the __getitem__ Method of its child, instead of calling its own __getitem__?

```
class Father(object):
    ''' Father class '''
    def __init__(self,name,gender):
        print('call __init__ Father')      
        self._name = name
        # trying to call Father's __getitem__ here
        self._gender=self[gender] 

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        print('call __getitem__  Father')
        return key

class Child(Father):
    ''' inherited from Father class '''
    def __init__(self, name, gender, age=None):
        print('call __init__ Child')
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(name, gender)
        self._age = age

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print('call __getitem__  Child')
        if self._name == 'Marie' and self._age == None:
            print('I am not sure, how old I am')
        return  super(self.__class__, self).__getitem__(key)

one=Child('Klaus','male','12')        
other=Child('Marie','female')
```

the error message that will occur is:

```
call __init__ Child
call __init__ Father
call __getitem__  Child
call __getitem__  Father
call __init__ Child
call __init__ Father
call __getitem__  Child
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-58-2d97b09f6e25>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('F:/python-workspace/more-fancy-getitem-fix/test.py', wdir='F:/python-workspace/more-fancy-getitem-fix')

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 601, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 66, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "F:/python-workspace/more-fancy-getitem-fix/test.py", line 26, in <module>
    other=Child('Marie','female')

  File "F:/python-workspace/more-fancy-getitem-fix/test.py", line 16, in __init__
    super(self.__class__, self).__init__(name, gender)

  File "F:/python-workspace/more-fancy-getitem-fix/test.py", line 6, in __init__
    self._gender=self[gender]

  File "F:/python-workspace/more-fancy-getitem-fix/test.py", line 21, in __getitem__
    if self._name == 'Marie' and self._age == None:

AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute '_age'
```

I would not expect this behavior. I was trying to inherit Child from Father adding functionality, so all of the above syntax is necessary and makes sense in  my more complex code. 
The first example of one=Child('Klaus','male','12') runs smothly and one can already see, that in the Father's constructor the Child's __getitem__ is called.
In the second example of other=Child('Marie','female') one can see why this reverse call troubles me. Here the code does not run until self._age = age is defined.

Appart from suggestions how this vice versa call might be useful and for what it was intended, I would be very grateful for solutions how to explicitly call the own __getitem__ method in Father. Just writing

```
self._gender=self.__getitem__(gender) #instead of
self._gender=self[gender]
```

unfortunately doesn't do the trick and produces the same error.

Comment: You should not use `super(self.__class__, self)` ever. That will recurse forever if I create a `class GrandChild(Child): pass`

Comment: Clarifying @Eric's point: In Python 3, you'd just use `super()` which is simple and correct. In Python 2, you need to call out the class where the method is defined explicitly by name, e.g. in your code, `super(Child, self)`, so in inheritance cases, the `super` magic can keep track of which overloads have already been called. `self.__class__` is going to change based on which level in the inheritance hierarchy you're at, and would only be correct for the first `super` call; after that, it would be passing the child's class, not the parent's like it should.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, I thought this syntax  is more general, and I would not have to rename here in case I want to change the Fathers class name. Have not thought of it the other way round.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix, just swap the order of initialization in the `Child` `__init__` so the `Child` attribute required by `Child.__getitem__` is initialized before it's needed:

```
def __init__(self, name, gender, age=None):
    print('call __init__ Child')
    self._age = age
    super(Child, self).__init__(name, gender)
```

This fix is unique to this specific scenario, but it's also usually the correct fix; in general, the only onus on parent classes is to try not to break subclassing unnecessarily, but they can't be expected to plan for a child class to create new class invariants and try to accommodate them in advance. The child class is expected to have complete knowledge of the parent, and it's the responsibility of the child class to ensure it doesn't break any behaviors of the parent, in this case, by making sure all new required attributes are defined before the parent might use methods that require them.

As for why it calls the child's `__getitem__`, that's just how subclassing works by default (not just in Python, but most OO languages). The `self` received by `Father.__init__` from `Child.__init__` is still a `Child` object, so lookup checks for `__getitem__` on `Child` first. If it didn't, you'd have confusing behavior where some indexing on `Child` invoked `__getitem__` and some didn't, which would make it really non-intuitive.

If for some reason you absolutely must use only `Father`'s `__getitem__` in `Father.__init__`, you just need to be explicit about which method you call. Instead of `self[gender]` or `self.__getitem__(gender)` (both of which go through normal lookup procedures), do `Father.__getitem__(self, gender)` which explicitly calls the `Father` version of the method (and also requires you to pass `self` explicitly, since you're using the unbound method rather than a bound method).

Another approach would be to define an attribute that indicates the instance is not fully initialized and bypass the child overload during the parent initializer so during initialization the parent method is invoked:

```
def __init__(self, name, gender, age=None):
    print('call __init__ Child')
    # Use double underscore prefix to make a private attribute of Child
    # not directly visible to parent or lower level children so no risk
    # of being reused by accident
    self.__in_parent_init = True
    super(Child, self).__init__(name, gender)
    self.__in_parent_init = False
    self._age = age

def __getitem__(self, key):
    if self.__in_parent_init:
        # Don't use Child specific features until Father initialized
        return super(Child, self).__getitem__(key)
    print('call __getitem__  Child')
    if self._name == 'Marie' and self._age == None:
        print('I am not sure, how old I am')
    return super(Child, self).__getitem__(key)
```

Comment: "just swap the order of initialization in the `Child` `__init__`" - that works here, but trying to fix things by reordering initialization in a more complex system can lead to a horrible web of subtle dependencies. It's better for constructors to never rely on subclass methods or subclass initialization.

Comment: @user2357112: Agreed that it's specific to this case. That said, inheritance is never as clean as we'd like it to be; if `Father` is from an outside code base, and didn't explicitly use `Father.__getitem__(self, gender)` (because it didn't anticipate a `Child` overriding `__getitem__` in a breaking way), that's not something that can be fixed on `Father`'s side, and it's usually reasonable to leave the onus of dealing with quirks in parent classes to the child class (which has complete knowledge of the parent, while the parent is not usually assumed to know anything about the child).

Comment: Thanks for the good response! switching would be indeed a solution, but mix things up that probably will give me headakes later. The explicit call of Father was the correct hint, Thanks.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: If `Father` is written that way, it really shouldn't be subclassed, though. The subclass *isn't* supposed to have complete knowledge of the implementation details of the parent, *especially* in the case you're describing where `Father` is 3rd-party code. Who knows how that 3rd-party library is going to change? If a class is written with its public methods relying on each other in a way that isn't specifically designed to support subclassing, it's not safe to override any of those public methods.

Comment: @user2357112: Python doesn't really believe in the kind of strict separation of knowledge that languages like Java and C++ adhere to. And it's not like `Father.__getitem__(self, gender)` is even demonstrably correct after all; now you _can't_ override `__getitem__` appropriately and consistently in `Child`, where with `self[gender]` it's consistent, and the `Child` can choose which behavior makes sense (even if it can get a bit hacky). `Father.__getitem__(self, gender)` is 50% likely to be unfixably _wrong_, which is the opposite of designing for subclassing.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I picked `Father.__getitem__` because the comments in the question say that line was trying to call `Father.__getitem__`; it's not supposed to pick up overrides. If the comments had indicated a different intention, I would have given different advice. While Python may not believe in completely locking classes out of each others' implementation details, having them rely on each others' implementation details is still an awful idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
# trying to call Father's __getitem__ here
self._gender=self[gender]
```

The `__getitem__` method used here will be looked up through the actual class of `self`. If `self` is an instance of `Child`, it will use `Child.__getitem__`. You could change this to use `Father.__getitem__` explicitly:

```
self._gender = Father.__getitem__(self, gender)
```

though your overall design is still kind of a mess, and it'll likely lead to more problems.

---

Unrelated but important:

```
super(self.__class__, self)
```

**NEVER DO THIS.** This will break if you do it in any class that ever gets subclassed. You have to provide the class name explicitly.

Comment: Short and precise, thanks! What I was trying to accomplish by my design, is to reuse code as efficient as possible by putting all stuff that is needed by other classes into Father and inherit.